# Getting incorrect results in program using nDPI library

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, packet-sniffers

I'm working on a program that utilizes the nDPI library to detect and classify network flows. However, I'm encountering an issue where the program is producing incorrect results. It keeps printing "Invalid category: -842150451" in a loop, and I'm having trouble identifying the cause of this issue.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tins/tins.h>
#include "ndpi_main.h"
#include "ndpi_api.h"
#include <fstream>

// Create a structure to store flow information
struct ndpi_flow_info {
    uint32_t src_ip;
    uint32_t dst_ip;
    uint16_t src_port;
    uint16_t dst_port;
    ndpi_protocol detected_protocol;
    struct ndpi_flow_struct *ndpi_flow;
};

struct flow_input_info {
  struct ndpi_flow_struct *flow; // The flow to process
  void *flow_id; // The flow identifier
  unsigned char in_pkt_dir;
  unsigned char seen_flow_beginning;
};

// Global variable for ndpi_struct
struct ndpi_detection_module_struct* ndpi_struct = ndpi_init_detection_module(ndpi_no_prefs);

// Function to read a network packet and fill the flow structure
int read_packet(struct ndpi_flow_info *flow, const Tins::PDU &pdu) {
    const Tins::IP &ip = pdu.rfind_pdu<Tins::IP>(); // Get the IP layer of the packet
    const Tins::TCP &tcp = pdu.rfind_pdu<Tins::TCP>(); // Get the TCP layer of the packet

    //copier ip dan ip2 qui est non const
    Tins::IP ip2 = pdu.rfind_pdu<Tins::IP>(); // Get the IP layer of the packet
    //void PDU::serialize(uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t total_sz)
    std::vector<uint8_t> packet_vector = ip2.serialize(); // Get the packet data
    const unsigned char* packet_data = packet_vector.data(); // Get the packet data
    const size_t packet_size = packet_vector.size(); // Get the packet size

    flow->src_ip = ip.src_addr();
    flow->dst_ip = ip.dst_addr();
    
    flow->src_port = tcp.sport();
    flow->dst_port = tcp.dport();

    flow->ndpi_flow = new struct ndpi_flow_struct;
    if (flow->ndpi_flow == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Memory allocation error" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Detect the protocol of the packet using nDPI
    //uint16_t packetlen = ip.tot_len();  // Get the packet length in bytes
    uint16_t packetlen = ip.size();  // Get the packet length in bytes = packet_size

    const Tins::Packet& packet = static_cast<const Tins::Packet&>(pdu);
    const Tins::Timestamp& timestamp = packet.timestamp();
    uint64_t time_ms = timestamp.seconds() * 1000 + timestamp.microseconds() / 1000;

    // Use the same flow structure as the input structure
    flow_input_info input;
    memset(&input, 0, sizeof(input));
    input.flow = flow->ndpi_flow; // Set the flow in the input structure
    input.flow_id = flow->ndpi_flow; // Set the flow id in the input structure


    ndpi_finalize_initialization (ndpi_struct); // Finalize the nDPI initialization

    flow->detected_protocol = ndpi_detection_process_packet(ndpi_struct, flow->ndpi_flow, packet_data, packet_size, time_ms, (const ndpi_flow_input_info *)&input);
    return 0;
}

// Function to print the detected protocol category
void print_category(struct ndpi_flow_info *flow) {
    if (ndpi_struct == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "nDPI struct is null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (flow->ndpi_flow == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "nDPI flow is null" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (flow->detected_protocol.category < 0 || flow->detected_protocol.category >= NDPI_PROTOCOL_NUM_CATEGORIES) {
        std::cout << "Invalid category: " << flow->detected_protocol.category << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    const char *category_name = ndpi_category_get_name(ndpi_struct, flow->detected_protocol.category);

    std::cout << "Flow between " << ((flow->src_ip >> 24) & 0xFF) << "." << ((flow->src_ip >> 16) & 0xFF) << "."
              << ((flow->src_ip >> 8) & 0xFF) << "." << (flow->src_ip & 0xFF) << ":" << flow->src_port << " and "
              << ((flow->dst_ip >> 24) & 0xFF) << "." << ((flow->dst_ip >> 16) & 0xFF) << "."
              << ((flow->dst_ip >> 8) & 0xFF) << "." << (flow->dst_ip & 0xFF) << ":" << flow->dst_port
              << " is classified as " << category_name << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Initialize nDPI
    if (ndpi_struct == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "nDPI initialization failed" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Read packets and detect protocols
    Tins::SnifferConfiguration config;
    config.set_promisc_mode(true); // Enable promiscuous mode
    config.set_filter("tcp"); // Set filter for TCP packets
    // Use the default interface
    Tins::NetworkInterface iface = Tins::NetworkInterface::default_interface();
    // print Default interface
    std::cout << "Default interface name: " << iface.name();
    std::wcout << " (" << iface.friendly_name() << ")" << std::endl;
    // Now instantiate the sniffer
    Tins::Sniffer sniffer(iface.name(),config);

    sniffer.sniff_loop([&](const Tins::PDU &pdu) -> bool {
        struct ndpi_flow_info flow;
        if (read_packet(&flow, pdu) == 0) {
            print_category(&flow);
        }
        return true;
    });

    
    ndpi_exit_detection_module(ndpi_struct);
    return 0;
}
```

I have already reviewed the nDPI documentation and relevant resources, including the following links:

https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/issues/282 (slightly outdated)
https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/blob/dev/example/ndpiSimpleIntegration.c
I have also performed several tests to identify the issue but haven't found any abnormalities so far.

I suspect that the problem might be related to the ndpi_struct or ndpi_flow variables, but I'm unable to pinpoint the exact error.

Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `-842150451` is a magic code and its your compiler trying to tell you something. In hex this value is `0xCDCDCDCD` which in msvc means "Uninitialized Heap Memory": [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/what-are-the-debug-memory-fill-patterns-in-visual-studio-c-and-windows)

Comment: @drescherjm Like I said it's not the compiler it's a variable value but maybe it can mean the same thing? I'll check

Comment: To be more clear `msvc` (Microsofts Compiler) in debug mode adds code that initializes heap memory given to your process to `0xCDCDCDCD`. If you ever see this value in any variable you know that it is extremely likely that either some part of the code has read an out of bounds location (that was some other variable that was not initialized) or some variable or variables have not been initialized but used as part of some calculation.

Comment: @Drescherjm You are an incredible person! THANKS ! I would never have had the idea of transforming my int into hexadecimal and then identifying it as an error code, it completely unblocks me, thank you very much. In addition to that I will know for the next time.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, what did I do wrong in my post? I seem to have been correct, I don't seem to enter these cases: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down though? Sorry but a negative vote without explanation prevents improvement.